# Trouble with my javascript function, I think with document.getElementById('vodObj').innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to write a JavaScript function that will update the labels and attributes of my CSS menu. The CSS menu I create dynamically with PHP and a database, and I want to update the CSS menu so the top item is the currently selected one, and the currently selected one does not appear in the list below it. Now that you know what I am trying to accomplish, here is my code:

```
var vodName = Array();
var vodAddress = Array();
var vodDate = Array();

function switchVod(vodID) {
    alert("switchVod ran");
    var x = document.getElementById("vod1");
    var y = x.getElementsByTagName("span");
    y[0].innerHTML = vodName[vodID];
    for (var i = 0; i < vodName.length; i++) {
        if (i != vodID) {
            var gameNum = i + 2;
            var gameID = "vod" + gameNum;
            var x = document.getElementByID(gameID);
            var y = x.getElementsByTagName("span");
            y[0].innerHTML = vodName[i]
            x.onclick = function () {
                switchVod(id);
            }
        }
    }
    alert("after for loop");
    alert("1"); //works
    document.getElementById('vodObj').innerHTML = 'some string';
    alert("2"); //doesn't work
    document.getElementById("vodDate").innerHTML = " some string ";
    alert("finished"); //doesn't work
}
```

Deeper in the webpage, after getting my information from the database and storing the strings I need in the `vodName`, `vodAddress`, and `vodDate` arrays, and creating the CSS menu and `<div id="vodObj">` and `<div id="vodDate">`, I initialize the page by calling

```
window.onload = switchVod(0);
```

It wasn't doing what I hoped, so I added some `alert()` calls to see how far into the function it was going before failing. `alert("after for loop")` worked, as did `alert("1")`. But, `alert("2")` does not pop up, and neither does `alert("finished")`, so I think the problem is with `document.getElementById('vodObj').innerHTML = 'some string';`.

Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You might need to post the relevant HTML the selectors are referring to. If possible, creating a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue would even be better and it would give the other developers a sandbox to test out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = switchVod(0);
```

**executes** `switchVod` and assigns the *return value* to `window.onload`. So it is very likely that the elements you are trying to access (`#vodObj` in particular) are not loaded yet.

You have to assign a function to `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    switchVod(0);
};
```

See also [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

---

There is an other problem which will encounter eventually:

```
x.onclick = function () {
    switchVod(id);
}
```

You never defined `id` anywhere, and if you define it inside the loop, you will run into closure issues. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

y[0].innerHTML = vodName[vodID];

At this point vodName is an empty array. Actually throughout all of this, you never provide any values to vodName. Please provide complete document.

Comment: That's true, but it wouldn't cause an error. This seems to be rather a comment than an answer. Please don't use the answer section for comments, wait until you have the comment privilege (50 rep).

Comment: Also if you read the question thoroughly, you will notice *"[...] after getting my information from the database and storing the strings I need in the vodName, vodAddress, and vodDate arrays [...]"*